# Windows 7: Prevent Guest Shutting Down Computer

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, guest-account

I have read many times that you can stop the Guest account on Windows 7 from shutting down the computer using

```
shutdown -s
```

in the command line by ensuring that

```
Local Policies\User Rights Assugnment\Shut Down The System
```

doesn't include the Guest account.

I've just tried this and was able to shut down the computer from the Guest account. I've also tried this in a clean install of Windows 7 Pro in VMware Player and get the same behaviour.

What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This yields a list of all groups with the ability to shut down the computer:

Windows Key -> in search type "Local Security Policy" and open the program.
Local Policies-> User Rights Assignment -> Double-click Shut down the system.

The Guest account is (probably) in one of those groups - I would guess 'Users' if it is not explicitly named in the list - verify group membership by running 'compmgmt.msc'

Of note: The guest account is, by default, a member of the 'YourDomain\Domain Users' group (if memory serves) which is a member of the Users Group.

If you want to verify group membership, running this command from powershell should spit it out assuming that you have the powershell activedirectory module:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership guest | select name
```

If using a command prompt is still allowing the activity, you can (and probably should) disable the command prompt for the guest account using gpedit.msc - it is under Group Policy->user configurations->administrative templates-> system -> "prevent access to the command prompt"